# Unable to drag ExtJS 4.0.7 tree node to panel and receive notifyDrop events

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a simple layout consisting of a `Ext.tree.Panel` on the left and a `Ext.panel.Panel` on the right. The contents of the right-hand panel are intended to be a d3 visualization.

The tree panel is defined as:

```
Ext.define('MyTreeModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    { name: 'id', type: 'string' }, 
    { name: 'text', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'ddGroup', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'myDropGroup' },
    { name: 'draggable', type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true }
  ]
});

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
  model: 'myTreeModel',
  autoSync: true,
  autoLoad: true,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'myendpoint.json',
    reader: { type: 'json' }
  }
});

Ext.define('MyTreePanel', {
  extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.mytreepanel',
  enableDD: true,                // not sure if this is necessary
  ddGroup: 'myDropGroup',        //             "
  rootVisible: false,
  store: myStore
}
```

And the panel that should receive the drop events is defined as:

```
Ext.define('MyDropPanel', {
  extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'component',
      id: 'd3Component',
      autoEl: { tag: 'div' }
    }
  ],
  ddGroup: 'myDropGroup',      // not sure if this is necessary
  enableDD: true,              //           "
  listeners: {
    render: initializeDropTarget,
    afterLayout: buildInitialD3Visualization // here's where the d3 SVG gets set up
  }
});

function initializeDropTarget(panel) {
  panel.dropTarget = Ext.dd.DropTarget.create(panel.el, {
    ddGroup: 'myDropGroup',
    notifyDrop: function(dd, e, data) {
      console.log("something dropped!");  // so far I have not seen this method fire.
    }
  });
}
```

I am new to ExtJS but these are the things I have tried:

1. I tried working with the plugin `treeviewdragdrop`. That allowed dragging and dropping within the tree but did not make and difference on whether my panel received drop events.
2. I tried adding the `enableDD` property but that doesn't actually seem to be a defined property on the ExtJS 4 `Panel` class. And, it doesn't seem to help so far.

I wonder if the existence of a "simple" div (where the visualization is to be displayed) is what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Drag and Drop operation in ExtJS you need to configurate drag source and drop target.

#### Drag Source

The easiest way how to setup tree as `dragSource` is by using [`Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop) plugin. In config of this plugin you should set name of `dragGroup`. By this identificator you can bind `dragSource` and `dropTarget` together.

```
var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,            
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            copy: true,
            dragGroup: 'myDDGroup'
        }
    },
});
```

#### Drop Target

Then you need to create `dropTarget` on your `Ext.panel.Panel`. For this you can use [`Ext.dd.DropTarget`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dd.DropTarget). This class implements some notify methods which you can override and use for handling drag and drop events.

The `notifyDrop` method is called when dragged element is dropped on target. If this method returns `true` drop is considered as successful.

Because you use as `dragSource` `treeviewdragdrop` the `data` parameter of every notify method also contains array of records which belongs to dragged tree nodes (`data.records`).

You can define your own class which extend `Ext.dd.DropTarget`:

```
Ext.define('myPanelDropTarget', {
    extend: 'Ext.dd.DropTarget',

    notifyEnter : function(source, e, data) {
        console.log('enter');
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    },                
    notifyOut : function(source, e, data) {
        console.log('out');
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    notifyOver : function(source, e, data) {
        console.log('over');
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    },                
    notifyDrop : function(source, e, data) {
        var me = this;
        console.log('drop');

        var text = data.records[0].get('text');

        var d3ComponentEl = me.panel.down('#d3Component').getEl();

        d3ComponentEl.insertHtml('beforeEnd', text + '<br />');                

        return true;
    }                           
});
```

#### Panel configured with drop target

Finally you can setup your panel as `dropTarget`. `dropTarget` will be created in `afterrender` event handler because you need to bind it to panel DOM element (and this element exists only after panel is rendered). Also you have to configure `dropTarget` with same `ddGroup` name as you use in `treeviewdragdrop` plugin config:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Drop Target Panel',
    border: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    items: [
        {
          xtype: 'component',
          id: 'd3Component',
          autoEl: { tag: 'div' }
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        'afterrender': function () {
            panel.dropZone = Ext.create('myPanelDropTarget', panel.getEl(), {
                ddGroup: 'myDDGroup',
                panel: panel
            });                    
        }
    }            
});
```

I also pass panel instance into `myPanelDropTarget` objet because for example I am adding dropped node's name into panel content.

#### Example

Fiddle with complete live example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/340**

Comment: Works great. BTW, one of the nicest ExtJS tutorials I've read. Thanks again.